# How to Update Data from Select Field Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have a number of select fields in which I'm saving the data to an associated table that stores two ids (no id column on the table, just two id's from each associated table). I have no problem with actually creating a record and after some tinkering updating an existing record. [select example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MAEed.png)

What I'm having trouble with is using Laravel `updateOrCreate` method, it doesn't update the original record but creates a new one + the old one. Basically, creates a second record instead of updating the original.

I'm not entirely sure what to do here. If I've already set a select value in the database but want to update that particular one, as well as have the option to set the second select how would I go about doing it? Code example below of how I'm getting my current (incorrect) solution

```html
$contractors = $request->get('contractors');
    if($contractors) {
       foreach ($contractors as $contractorId) {
        if (isset($contractorId)) {
         $interestedContractor->updateOrCreate([
          'project_id' => $project->getId(),
          'contractor_id' => $contractorId
         ]);
        }
       }
      }
```

As this is my first question if anything is unclear please let me know and I will clarify.

Also the relationship is setup by a hasManyThrough if that helps at all.

Comment: It seems like it's pivot table and you use many-to-many relationship. If it isn't the case, I suggest you set up that relation. Then use sync() method. https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#updating-many-to-many-relationships

Comment: @BülentAkgül thank you for your answer, I've set up the relationship as a hasManyThrough but currently looking at an trying your solution.